# How to fetch 4 JSON (API) Responses to one view in backbone.js using Model/Collection

Tags: json, backbone.js, view, collections, model

I'm learning how to use `backbone.js`. I got 4 JSON APIs, and I need to collect all the responses and fetch the total response to single view

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use collection/model to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a 2 call main view with sub views. It gets a lot more complex then that. But that should get you started.

These are the main 2 collections that get the data. If you want to break it down further (depends on needs) you can create a `Model` and then assign it to the collection using `model: CityModel` (in this case).

```
var Cities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=me',
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.geonames;
    }
});

var Earthquakes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=me',
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.earthquakes;
    }
});
```

then the sub views, standard: here you can create events for each.

```
var EarthquakeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template('<strong><%=eqid%></strong> <%=lng%> <%=lat%> magnitude: <%=magnitude%>'),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
        return this;
    }
});
```

Notice here you can `extend` a view so you dont have to repeat yourself.

```
var CityView = EarthquakeView.extend({
    template: _.template('<strong><%=toponymName%></strong> <%=lng%> <%=lat%>')
});
```

The main view..

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(opt) {
        // attach to the main body
        $(opt['main']).append(this.el)

        this.earthquakesEl = $('<ol>');
        this.earthquakes = new Earthquakes()
        this.earthquakes.on('sync', _.partial(this.renderList, EarthquakeView, this.earthquakesEl), this);
        this.earthquakes.fetch()

        this.citiesEl = $('<ol>');
        this.cities = new Cities()
        this.cities.on('sync', _.partial(this.renderList, CityView, this.citiesEl), this);
        this.cities.fetch()

        // initialize the element
        this.render();
    },
    renderList: function(view, el, collection) {
        collection.forEach(function(model) {
            el.append(new view({model: model}).render().el)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.earthquakesEl);
        this.$el.append(this.citiesEl);

        return this;
    }
});

new View({ main: $('body') });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9y574y8/2/

There are 2 collection calls that are made independently, and there are 2 listeners that wait for them to finish and then place it on the main view. If you have any issue let me know. I think its pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have done some research today and working with jQuery $.when to combine both the responses

Comment: I dont know your exact use case for that, but 99% of the time, when i need to load things asynchronously, i never try to combine them, you're just going to annoy the user. its best to just load (when possible) as many pieces apart and stitch them as they finish, not wait until everything is finished and then stitch them. On another note, if you can provide some code as to what youre actually doing, i can be a lot more helpful.